# Uncheck asp.net checkboxlist values using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have an asp.net checkbox list and the values of checkboxlist are binded from database. my requirement is to uncheck the checkboxes on a button click. Can someone please suggest me a way on how to uncheck the checkboxes using javascript or jquery. Thanks

Comment: How do they look like? DO you want to uncheck all of them?

Comment: yes i want to uncheck all

Comment: You can do:  $('#button').click(function() {
   $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});    -- the selector will scan all of the input controls and filter it via 'checkbox' type, then internal code will switch their 'checked' property to 'true'.

Answer (score 1):

Possible [Similar QUestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

```
    //Assuming you have this object model structure in your ASPX page.
<input type="text" name="openid_username" />
<input type="text" name="openid_identifier" />

Upon screen render, it gets  translated to:
<asp:TextBox ID="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_openid_username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_openid_identifier" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<input type='button' id='myButton' value='Check Button'>
```

You can set the checked property of the checkboxes via below jquery code:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('input[name$=openid_username]').prop('checked',true);
$('input[name$=openid_identifier]').prop('checked',true);
  });
```

Also, please see this jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wwRwF/).

Answer (score 0):

Give the checkboxes a css class say `.mycheckbox`

```
// On:
$(".mycheckbox").checked(true);

// Off:
$(".mycheckbox").checked(false);

// Toggle:
$(".mycheckbox:checked").checked(false);
$(".mycheckbox:not(:checked)").checked(true);
```

Comment: hi tom, the checboxes are binded dynamically from database. will this solution work in such case? thanks for your reply

Comment: user545359, yes it should, it will not mangle the CssClass name. Asp.net will mangle IDs so if you stick to that you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Jquery

```
function checkAll(formname)
{
  var checkboxes = new Array(); 
  checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
      checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}; 

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#unCheck').click(function () {
         checkAll("form1");
      });
});
```

### HTML

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:CheckBoxList id="check1" AutoPostBack="True" TextAlign="Right" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
```

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Put an html button:

```
<input type="button" value="Uncheck all" onclick="uncheckCheckboxes()" />
```

Write javascript function `uncheckCheckboxes` (assuming your checkboxlist id is `cbl`):

```
function uncheckCheckboxes()
{
   $("#<%# cbl.ClientID %> input").prop("checked",false);
}
```

Comment: not working  below should work  $("#<%=Checkbox1.ClientID %>").prop("checked",false);